# Prove $f$ is bijective if and only if the inverse relation $f^{-1}$ is a function from $B$ to $A$.

Tags: functions, logic, alternative-proof, natural-deduction

Working on the book: Richard Hammack. "Book of Proof" (p. 251)

> Theorem 12.3 Let $f$ : $A \to B$ be a function. Then $f$ is bijective if and only if the inverse relation $f^{-1}$ is a function from $B$ to A.

Defining inverse relation $f^{-1}$ as:
$$
\forall x\forall y((y,x) \in f^{-1} \leftrightarrow ((x,y) \in A \times B \land (x,y) \in f))
$$
***$(\implies)$*** I need to show:
$$
\forall x(x \in B \to \exists!y(y \in A \land (x,y) \in f^{-1}))
$$

Rules of inference used can be found in Appendix C of this book: [forall x: An Introduction to Formal Logic.](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf)

My questions:
The author justifies the proof by invoking a theorem. I tried to do it with these four premises. Is this a valid proof ?

**Proof** using Fitch-Style natural deduction system (ommited obvious inferences):

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{1.\,\forall x(x \in A \to \exists! y(y \in B \land (x,y) \in f) \qquad\textit{f is a function from A to B}\\
2.\,\forall x\forall x'((x \in A \land x' \in A \land x \neq x') \to f(x) \neq f(x')) \qquad\textit{f is injective}\\
3.\,\forall y(y \in B \to \exists x(x \in A \land f(x) = y)) \qquad\textit{f is surjective}\\
4.\,\forall x\forall y((y,x) \in f^{-1} \leftrightarrow ((x,y) \in A \times B \land (x,y) \in f))
}{
  \fitch{5.\,b \in B}{
   6.\,b \in B \to \exists x(x \in A \land f(x) = b)) \Ae{3}
   7.\,\exists x(x \in A \land f(x) = b)) \ie{6,5}
   \fitch{8.\,a \in A \land f(a)=b}{
     9.\,f(a)=b \ce{8}
     10.\,(b,a) \in f^{-1} \leftrightarrow ((a,b) \in A \times B \land (a,b) \in f) \Ae{4}
     11.\,a \in A \ce{8}
     12.\,b \in B \ce{5}
     13.\,(a,b) \in A \times B \\
     14.\,(a,b) \in f \\
     15.\,(a,b) \in A \times B \land (a,b) \in f \ci{14,9}
      16.\,(b,a) \in f^{-1} \be{15,14}
      17.\,a \in A \land (b,a) \in f^{-1} \ci{11,16}
      \fitch{18.\,c \in A \land (b,c) \in f^{-1}}{
        19.\,(b,c) \in f^{-1} \ce{18}
        20.\,(c,b) \in f\\
        \fitch{21.\,a \neq c}{
         22.\,(a \in A \land c \in A \land a \neq c) \to f(a) \neq f(c) \Ae{2}
         23.\,(a \in A \land c \in A \land a \neq c) \ci{21}
         24.\,f(a) \neq f(c) \ie{22,23}
         25.\,(a,b) \in f\\
         26.\,(c,b) \in f\R{20}
         27.\,f(c)=b\\
         28.\,f(a)=f(c) \qe{27,9}
         29.\,\bot \ne{24,28}
        }\\
        30.\,a = c \IP{21-29}
      }\\
      31.\,(c \in A \land (b,c) \in f^{-1}) \to a = c \ii{18,30}
      32.\,\forall z(z \in A \land (b,z) \in f^{-1}) \to a = z \Ai{31}
      33.\,a \in A \land (b,a) \in f^{-1} \land \forall z(z \in A \land (b,z) \in f^{-1}) \to a = z \ci{17,32}
      34.\,\exists y(y \in A \land (b,a) \in f^{-1} \land \forall z(z \in A \land (y,z) \in f^{-1}) \to a = z) \Ei{33}
      35.\,\exists!y(y \in A \land (a,y) \in f^{-1})
    }\\
    36.\,\exists!y(y \in A \land (a,y) \in f^{-1}) \Ee{7,8-35}
  }\\
  37.\,b \in B \to \exists!y(y \in A \land (x,y) \in f^{-1}) \ii{5-36}
  38.\,\forall x(x \in A \to \exists!y(y \in A \land (x,y) \in f^{-1})) \Ai{37}
}
$